# Bulk move repository to another namespace inside gitlab

Tags: postgresql, gitlab, gitlab-ci

It's quite straightforward how to *manually* move a repository to a new namespace.
I have about 200+ projects spread between a few users that need to consolidate.
Is there any suitable `GitLab Shell` command to do it?
Perhaps a few sql commands using PostgreSQL?

```sh
sudo -u gitlab-psql -i 
# and then
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/psql --port 5432 -h /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql -d gitlabhq_production
gitlabhq_production=#
```

I'm close to the answer but not there yet...

```sh
select id,name,path from namespaces;
select id,name,path,description from projects;
\q
```

Another idea is using a bash job, a quite dirty idea will be to clone the subject repos on a temp area, modify the origin and push back to the new namespace.